# pointerIndex out of range exception in photo editor

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm facing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range error while working on photo editor android app. I don't know why I'm facing this error. Here I'll post my class which gives this error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range

I'm not able to post full code here, so please go and view my code here

```
`https://pastebin.com/KCzcjmuA`
```

If you want full logs then feel free to ask me. Thanks in advance. NOTE: I'm here after hours of googling without luck.

Comment: `I'm not able to post full code here` and you should not. Post only **relevant** part of code.

Comment: `I'm facing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` show the stacktrace, and code where it appears.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YqY99fxz this is link to logcat and https://pastebin.com/KCzcjmuA this is to code

Comment: Hey! I fixed it by setting pointer id to 0 (Wasted hours). Anyways thank you.